# Linux Mint 17.3 Wifi issue

Tags: linux

I have a HP Notebook I just put Linux Mint 17.3 on it and now the wifi doesn't work unless hooked up to the ethernet. I have gone to driver manager and it doesn't display anything after loading the cache. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need Wifi drivers.

You will first need an active connection to the internet. You said Ethernet was working, so just hook yourself up to ethernet real quick.

Now go into `Driver Manager`, which should either be in the Menu, or System Settings.

Wait for it to refresh the cache and load. There, you should see your wifi card showing up. I recommend choosing the Recommended driver.

Click Apply when you have selected the driver, and wait for it to finish, then restart when it tells you to. When logging in after the restart, you should have Wifi.

Comment: I've read that in another thread after I posted my question and it refreshed the cache but didn't load anything in the driver manager

Comment: Update: My HP is picking up he wifi but not connecting. It says the signal is too weak but my windows HP Elitebook is connected and saying the signal is strong. How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe a faulty wifi card? Did you have Windows on it previously and was it ever connected?

Comment: It had windows 10 and would connect to my wifi automatically with a strong signal

Comment: Have you tried Linux Mint 18.x? Maybe those would work better for you? If not, then update the kernel and see after a restart if it is working. However, the Driver Manager not showing anything has gotten me puzzled.

Comment: Go to the Update Manager > View > Linux Kernels. Click Continue, and you should see the kernels. Go to 4.8, and install the latest kernel. If 4.8 doesn't work, try 4.10. Make sure you are connected to the internet while you are doing this. Then do a reboot and see if you are able to connect to the internet.

Comment: If I solved it, make sure you click the little checkmark below the votes on my answer. This lets others know that this is the correct answer. And No Problem. I am always happy to help others.

Comment: I installed mint 18.2 and I'm having the same problem but now it won't even pick up my phones hotspot

Comment: Update it just picked up my phone but has yet to pick up my wifi

Comment: Did you try and see if you can find your wifi card in Driver Manager? Maybe it is using an alternative driver.

Comment: Run in terminal `inxi -i | pastebin` or run `inxi -i` without pastebin and edit your original question with the output. If you run it with pastebin, make sure you link it here.

Comment: I forgot to add. Make sure you sensor out your IP address. That can tell others of personal information. So, I would recommend pasting the output of `inxi -i` and taking out your ip address from the output.

Comment: Open Terminal using Ctrl+Alt+T, then type in `inxi -i` into the commandline, and paste the output in your question, but make sure you find `WAN IP` and take that out when pasting the output.

Comment: So I typed in the inxi -i and it says card 1 is down, wan ip none detected, ip-v4 N/A

Comment: What type of card is it? What is its exact model?

Comment: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe

Comment: Seems like this issue is a common problem with users of that wifi card. Follow the steps here: http://www.linuxlinx.com/2016/05/install-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-driver-ubuntu-linuxmint.html

Comment: My computer says that won't work because https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/tree/rock.new_btcoex can't be found

Comment: Try `git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git` instead. Seems like that branch is no longer maintained. That also means the next line will need to be `cd rtlwifi_new` instead.

Comment: It's unable to locate

Comment: Did it successfully clone the git?

Comment: No. What does it mean when it says module sudo not found?

Comment: Are you typing sudo twice? Have you tried restarting the system? It shouldn't say 'sudo not found' ever unless you are trying to load the module sudo. Have you followed the instructions in the link I sent you + the instructions I told you? Make sure you are typing the commands correctly.

Comment: Yes and now it's not even showing wifi as an option for my internet

Comment: I honestly have no idea how else to help you. That is all I know. If you followed the instructions correctly and read them, then it should work. Maybe I am missing something, but I don't have that good of knowledge on linux myself

Comment: Well thank you for your help and this might help somebody else